# Linux installs - where should I put them?

Tags: linux, eclipse, xubuntu, file-location

I am relatively new to Linux, I am using Xubuntu 10.04.

A lot of the software I download from the net, e.g. Aptana/Eclipse are just ZIP files that I open and run.

1. I wish them to be in a specific folder where I can reach them from everywhere when I run "Eclipse".
2. I want them to be available to all users.
3. I want to be able to start them from the drop-down menu on the desktop.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is some kind of "Filesystem Hierarchy Standard":

> The Filesystem Hierarchy Standard (FHS) defines the main directories
>   and their contents in Linux operating systems. For the most part, it
>   is a formalization and extension of the traditional BSD filesystem
>   hierarchy.

I would put that stuff to:

```
/opt/   Optional application software packages
```

Read yourself: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard

For the rest of your questions:

1. That's a matter of having the path to the binary / script you want to launch in the PATH variable. According to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables you want to do this via `/etc/environment`. You could also create a 'symbolic link' to the binary or write a launch script which you then place into `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin`.
2. See 1.
3. For that you have to create a [.desktop file](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/desktop-file-utils) and install it (make an entry in the menu to it) via [xdg-desktop-menu](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/xdg-desktop-menu.1.html).

Comment: +1. But if only I will use the software, why must I become root and install the software to `/opt`?  Wouldn't it be wiser to install the software to somewhere underneath `/home/unforgettableid` instead?  If you were me, which exact location would you choose?

Comment: @unforgettableid: you can "place files" wherever you like. `/opt/local` is a convention. the same way you can "place files" wherever you like on MSFT-Windows or on MacOSX. you will break conventions. if that is not an issues to you: go ahead and place the files wherever you like.

Answer (score 2):

You should use your system's package manager to do installation whenever possible. The package will be automatically located in an appropriate place. On Xubuntu, it's aptitude/apt-get/synaptic/Ubuntu Software Center. See [Adding, Removing and Updating Applications](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.10/add-applications/C/index.html).

Comment: Yes, true. But not all software is available via the package managers.